# Android Jpeg Capturing (CameraX) produces broken black images with size 192 KB on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

**Goal**

I tried to convert the [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic) sample code into a separate class `CapturingProcess`

- which binds the `capture` use case in `new CapturingProcess(context, lifecycleOwner)`
- which offers a simple `requestPicture()` method to capture multiple pictures (e.g. one each second)

**Bug description**

- Executing `requestPicture()` multiple times produces

  - 4 normal JPEG pictures (> 1 MB)
  - **all other** JPEG files are completely **black** and always **192 KB** large

[image: Generated JPEG pictures]

**Steps to reproduce**

- Checkout and build [sample app](https://github.com/hb0/cameraX5thJpegBlack192Kb)
- Run the app and hit the button 5-10 times
- Check the images in `Android/media/com.example.cameraxblackjpegbug/CameraXBlackJpegBug/`
- you see that only the first 4 Jpeg pictures are ok

  - *(only on some devices, see "Tested on" section)*

**Expected outcome**

- All pictures are non-broken
- each time `capturingProcess.requestPicture()` is called a non-broken Jpeg picture is captured

**Tested on**

- Pixel 3a Andorid 10 (reproduces bug)

  - Note: I had a similar bug with camera2 before but was not able to fix it back then
- Huawei P smart 2019 Android 9 (does not reproduce bug)

  - has no "manual sensor" feature

**Known workarounds**

- When I create a `new CapturingProcess()` e.g. after the button was clicked 3 times the bug does not occur

  - however, this is not acceptable. In my use case I need to capture pictures each seconds for a long time in the background so in order to save resources I can't to create a new Instance each time.

**Relevant code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var capturingProcess: CapturingProcess

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Create Capturing Process
        capturingProcess = CapturingProcess(applicationContext, this)

        // Register capture action to button
        fab.setOnClickListener { capturingProcess.requestPicture() }
    }
}
```

```
class CapturingProcess(context: Context, lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {

    private var context: Context = context
    private var outputDirectory: File
    private var mainExecutor: Executor
    private lateinit var cameraControl: CameraControl
    private lateinit var cameraInfo: CameraInfo
    private var capture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var lensFacing: Int = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
    private var lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner

    fun requestPicture() {
        capture?.let { imageCapture ->
            val photoFile = createFile(outputDirectory, FILENAME, PHOTO_EXTENSION)
            val metadata = ImageCapture.Metadata().apply {
                isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            }
            imageCapture.takePicture(photoFile, metadata, mainExecutor, imageSavedListener)
        }
    }

    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this.context)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {

            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            capture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setTargetName("Capture")
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .build()

            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            try {
                val camera =
                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this.lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, capture)
                cameraControl = camera.cameraControl
                cameraInfo = camera.cameraInfo
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                throw IllegalStateException(e)
            }

        }, this.mainExecutor)
    }

    private val imageSavedListener = object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {

        override fun onError(imageCaptureError: Int, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: $message")
        }

        override fun onImageSaved(photoFile: File) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: ${photoFile.absolutePath}")

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                context.sendBroadcast(
                    Intent("android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE", Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
                )
            }

            val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(photoFile.extension)
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                context, arrayOf(photoFile.absolutePath), arrayOf(mimeType), null
            )
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val FILENAME = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val PHOTO_EXTENSION = ".jpg"
        private const val TAG = "CapturingProcess"


        private fun createFile(
            baseFolder: File,
            @Suppress("SameParameterValue") format: String,
            @Suppress("SameParameterValue") extension: String
        ) = File(
            baseFolder,
            SimpleDateFormat(
                format,
                Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + extension
        )

        fun getOutputDirectory(context: Context): File {
            val appContext = context.applicationContext
            val mediaDir = context.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
                File(it, context.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
            }
            return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists()) {
                mediaDir
            } else {
                appContext.filesDir
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        this.mainExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory(context)
        bindCameraUseCases()
    }
}
```

**Question**

- To clarify: I want to find the bug in the sample code/project.
- Thus, my question is: Why does the described bug occur when I execute `requestPicture()` > 4 times on the same `CapturingProcess` instance but not when I create new instances after executing it e.g. 3 times - I.e. how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the capture process of all 5 images is executed sequentially after another and not partially multi-threaded? Because by your description a multi-threading issue would be a possible reason and also explain why the first 4 images work (picture capture process completed before the next request comes in). After the 4th image because of a overfull disk cache the capture process takes more time and the multi-threading issue starts destroying data.

Comment: @Robert The CameraX API makes sure only one request is handled at a time. Additionally I had extra code which ignored further requests until die first finished. Also, the bug occurs when I wait 5 seconds after each time hitting the capture button. Thus, i don't think that's the case here. Also, this does not explain why it works when a new "CapturingProcess" instance is created - it does not use different threads. The threading is done in CameraX internally as far as I understood. Please correct me if I am wrong.